# Why new users can access some folders in my computer and not others?

Tags: windows-10

I created a new user. That new user can access all folders in D: but not in H:

And I have no idea why.

To access files in H: the user needs permission from administrator. However to access files in D: a new user can just do it.

Basically I want local non administrator user to be able to access only his documents and folders/files I approve.

How would I accomplish that?

Comment: @somebadhat Powershell for this is inefficient, unless it's needing to be done within a script.  Generally speaking, PowerShell is almost always more inefficient outside of scripting.  For example, using that PowerShell example is 372 characters and a nightmare to have to type, versus the 38 - 48 characters required for using `icacls` with a system [non-powershell] variable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the new user to the directory properties of `H:`

- **GUI:**

  1. **This PC** > Right-click `H:` > *Properties*
  2. **Security Tab** > *Edit...* > *Add...*

     1. **Object names to select:** `<username>`
     2. Use checkboxes under *Allow* to assign permissions

        1. If needing to assign more granular permissions, click *Advanced*
        2. *Add* > *Select a Principal*
        3. *Basic Permissions:* or *Show advanced permissions:*
- **CLI:**

  ```powershell
  :: # Grant User Permissions to Edit ::
     Cmd /C Icacls "H:" /Grant %UserName%:M

     :: # OR ::

  :: # Grant User Full Permissions ::
     Cmd /C Icacls "H:" /Q /C /T /Grant %UserName%:F

  :: # Help ::
     Icalcs /?
  ```